# How to apply my custom to every arrow in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I want to custom, not a single arrow using `\path[options]`, but every newly created arrow.
For instance, the options are `->, red, line width=1pt`.

I have tried

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[paths={->, red, line width=1pt}]
```

and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[edges={->, red, line width=1pt}]
```

But none of them works.

**My question**: How to apply my custom to every arrow?

Comment: What do you mean with newly created arrows? Maybe `[every path/.append style={->}]`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks! It works. May I ask in addition how to only apply to paths created after a certain line?

Comment: Just do `\tikzset{every path/.append style={…}` right before them. (Or put in a scope so that it only applies to the paths inside that scope.)